# Is it possible to get before and after comparison of 2 images with slider in KIVY

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Is it possible to get an image comparison slider like jquery script in kivy?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question should have your effort to solve the task. Here you post abstract question which people will likely delete rather answer. Code is good, environment, screenshots, error codes if any. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt that there's a in-build function in Kivy to take in 2 images and produce an image comparison (I could not find any "black box" function that does that)

Is it possible? Well nothing is impossible for most cases in coding. I found a HTML solution. It may be a good idea to take it and understand its logic. Then based on your expertise convert it to a KIVY solution.

Taken from w3 schools : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_image_compare

Have fun learning how to do it! Hope you'll figure out one day!

Comment: I have tried with a splitter, scatter plane, slider, and as well as canvas. The whole overlay image is resized or moving. I couldn't get this effect quite. Since I am relatively new to this as well.